# Need to unzip files and then move to AWS S3 bucket automatically

Tags: ubuntu, file-transfer

I have a directory in ubuntu example:

```
/home/ubuntu/mainfiles/
```

where only zip files get uploaded daily. I need to unzip these files and move the extracted files to S3 bucket. Each unzipped file's files should be moved to s3 at 5 minutes interval. I also need to make sure duplicate files doesn't get uploaded to s3.

How do I write a script for this ?

What I am currently doing is

- Copy the oldest file from `/home/ubuntu/mainfiles/` directory each 5 minute withs `cron` and then storing it on a `temp1` directory.
- Then I unzip all the files from `temp1` directory and move the extracted files to `temp2` directory.
- Finally I move all files on `temp2` directory to s3.

But I think above approach might fail because I have to clean the `temp1` folder each time. Also duplicate files can get moved to s3 because I don't know how to get the file name and rename it with random name and then move to s3.

Can someone provide a demo shell script for this with right approach  ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can automate using bash...

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR='/home/ubuntu/mainfiles'
s3_DIR='/mnt/s3bucket'
for i in $DIR/*.zip;do
    unzip $DIR/$i.zip -d $S3_DIR/ && mv $DIR/$i.zip $DIR/$i.zip.done # extract and mark
    fdupes -dN $S3_DIR  # remove duplicate files
done
```

> add this in cronjob @every 5 minutes

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... But it is producing an error while running the script like this -> https://imgur.com/a/clASOOh

Comment: you need to install unzip, fdupes command. ```apt install unzip fdupes```

Comment: unzip is already installed .... If you look at the image there is double slash // in path output .... Also I only need to unzip one file at a time. (may be the oldest modified one first) and then unzip it to S3.  And then again another one after 5 minutes ... Seems like your script is trying to unzip all the files at once in the $DIR